# Curly braces in Hasse diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I need to create a Hasse diagram (i.e., lattice diagram) in LaTeX.  Right now, I have the following code in tikz-cd.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz, tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= (a).base]
\node[scale=.85] (a) at (0,0){
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
& & K_1 
\arrow[ddll]
\arrow[d]\\
& & k_1
    \arrow[ddll,sloped,pos=0.7,"\text{degree $p$}"]\\
K_0 \arrow[d,swap,"\text{degree 2} \, \,"] & & \\
k_0 & &
\end{tikzcd}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hasse diagram]

I would like to add labeled vertical brackets to the diagram off to the side, preferably curly braces.  For instance, I would like a vertical brace to the left of the diagram, labeled with 'H' and spanning from K_0 on the bottom to K_1 on the top. (Note:  this is *not* the entire diagram -- the brace should extend down to K_0, not all the way down to k_0 at the bottom of the diagram.)

What is the simplest way to add these braces?  Can I do it in tikz-cd?  If not, what is the simplest alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't  know how to add a brace emcompassing only part of the height of the figure with tikz, but it's easy to obtain it with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath, pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\psset{linejoin=1}
\everypsbox{\footnotesize}
$ \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.3cm, colsep=2.5cm]
    \pnode[-4pt, 1.5ex]{K1}\phantom{K₁} & K₁ \\
    & k₁ \\
    \pnode[-4pt, -0.5ex]{K0}K₀ \\
    k₀
    \psset{nodesep=4pt, labelsep=2pt}
    \ncline{3,1}{1,2}\ncline{4,1}{2,2}\nbput[nrot=:U]{\text{degree $ p $}}
    \ncline{1,2}{2,2}\ncline{4,1}{3,1}\naput[nrot=:U]{\text{degree $ 2 $}}
    \psset{braceWidthInner=3pt,braceWidthOuter=3pt, braceWidth =0.8pt, nodesepB=-4pt, nodesepA=-1pt}
    \psbrace(K1)(K0){H}
  \end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look that easy, since I don't know pstricks!  But I'll try to learn enough to figure out what you did.  Thanks.

Comment: It's much easier to learn than TikZ, because it uses a LaTeX syntax, and it's well documented (by modules, no more than 130 pages each time).

Comment: @Barry: If you want to understand what happens, take a look at the documentation of `pst-node` , and especially § 7, *Mathematical diagrams and graphs*, pp. 21–23.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `cases` environment will do:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath, tikz, tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

$ H \begin{cases}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= (a).base]
      \node[scale=.85] (a) at (0,0){
        \begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
          & & K_1
          \arrow[ddll]
          \arrow[d]\\
          & & k_1
          \arrow[ddll,sloped,pos=0.7,"\text{degree $p$}"]\\
          K_0 \arrow[d,swap,"\text{degree 2} \, \,"] & & \\
          k_0 & &
        \end{tikzcd}
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{cases} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This extends all the way to the bottom of the diagram, which I don't want.  Perhaps the capitalization in my OP made it unclear.  I have updated the OP to make clear that the brace should extend only partway down.

Answer (score 3):

With `\left\lbrace` and `\right.`

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz, tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
$H \left\lbrace 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= (a).base]
    \node[scale=.85] (a) at (0,0){
        \begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
        & & K_1 
        \arrow[ddll]
        \arrow[d]\\
        & & k_1
        \arrow[ddll,sloped,pos=0.7,"\text{degree $p$}"]\\
        K_0 \arrow[d,swap,"\text{degree 2} \, \,"] & & \\
        k_0 & &
        \end{tikzcd}
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\right.$    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This extends all the way to the bottom of the diagram, which I don't want.  Perhaps the capitalization in my OP made it unclear.  I have updated the OP to make clear that the brace should extend only partway down.

Answer (score 3):

A solution for tikz-cd using `decorations.pathreplacing`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
    \vphantom{K_1} \arrow[dd, start anchor=north, end anchor=south, no head, xshift=-1em, decorate, decoration={brace,mirror}, "H" left=3pt] & & K_1 \arrow[ddll] \arrow[d]\\
    & & k_1 \arrow[ddll,sloped,pos=0.7,"\text{degree $p$}"]\\
    K_0 
        \arrow[d,swap,"\text{degree 2} \, \,"] & & \\
    k_0 & &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\vphantom{K_1}` to ensure that the anchor north is at the correct place.

Following answers of other questions were helpful

- [How to insert a big brace, arrows crossing etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336536/8917)
- [Problems with tikzcd diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256562/8917) *(BTW title of this question is too generic.)*
- [Overhead brace in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466158/8917)
- [Horizontal and vertical braces below and next to a tabular table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388864/8917)
- [tikz-cd: Error: No shape named tikz@f@1-0-1 found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172254/8917) (place `{}` to draw an arrow to an empty cell)

and also following weblink

- https://spartanideas.msu.edu/2018/05/23/grouping-rows-of-a-matrix/

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much for adding these even two years after the question had been answered! My application needed a horizontal brace, and the key line was `\arrow[rrr, start anchor=west, end anchor=east, no head, yshift=1em, decorate, decoration={brace}, "T" above=3pt]`.