# TL2018 (MacTeX) and TikZ calligraphy library

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3, latex3, tikzlibrary, calligraphy

Under MacTeX 2018 the following TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}

\begin{document}

\tikz\draw[decorate,decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=4mm},ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,8);

\end{document}
```

gives the following warning

```
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "kernel/deprecated-variant"
* 
* Variant form 'VnV' deprecated for base form '\spath_get:nnN'. One should not
* change an argument from type 'N' to type 'V': base form only accepts a
* single token argument.
*************************************************
```

and these errors:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/spath3/tikzlibrarycalligraphy.code.tex:707: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \g__prg_map_int 

l.707 ...igraphy pen copperplate}{\l__cal_tmpa_tl}

/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/spath3/tikzlibrarycalligraphy.code.tex:707: You can't use `\char"1' after \advance.
\int_gincr:N ..._global:D \tex_advance:D #1\c_one
```

I reported the warning in [Warning with tikzlibrary calligraphy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408378/warning-with-tikzlibrary-calligraphy), but the errors are new with TL2018 -- TL2017 does not give the errors.

Comment: This probably comes from the fact that the expl3 code has just been updated, one of the release notes mentions `- Deprecated functions expiring at end of 2017 are removed`, so the calligraphy people or who ever might not have been keeping up.

Comment: Though, I only get the warning, no error. Have you updated your MacTeX?

Comment: @LoopSpace is the author

Comment: Ahh, I updated to todays updates, now I also get that error

Comment: Fixed on github, but I'm waiting to be told that I shouldn't be using l3 internals in that way so it might be a short while before it makes it to CTAN. https://github.com/loopspace/spath3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The LaTeX team have been working on tightening up some `expl3` internals. This can have an impact where third-parties have used internal code from the kernel: that is the case here. For the present, it can be fixed by adding

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_zero_new:N \g__prg_map_int 
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

before loading the various TikZ libraries.

Comment: Thanks. Follow-up: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442132/undefined-sequence-error-for-with-calligraphy-tikz-library.

Comment: @cfr Just found that your nice answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372682/121799 also seems to need that fix.