# Undefined sequence error with calligraphy tikz library

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, expl3, tikzlibrary, calligraphy

The following MWE is from `calligraphy`'s manual (p.9) with [Joseph Wright's workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429862/) for the library's use of obsolete functions:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_zero_new:N \g__prg_map_int 
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\tikz \calligraphy [copperplate] (0,0) .. controls
+(1,−1) and +(−1,1) .. ++(3,0) [this stroke
style={light,taper=start}] +(0,0) .. controls
+(1,−1) and +(−1,1) .. ++(3,0) [this stroke
style={heavy}] +(0,0) .. controls +(1,−1) and
+(−1,1) .. ++(3,0) [this stroke
style={light,taper=end}] ;
\end{document}
```

However, I get the following compilation error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.20 style={light,taper=end}] ;

?
```

What's the best workaround or fix? I realise that `\GenericError` is defined, as `latexdef` says so. Indeed, it gives a definition which uses `\@err@`, too. So, presumably, `\@err@` should be defined before `\GenericError` is called, but isn't. But none of this really explains why I get an error with the manual's code at all.

The library also relies on `\__prop_split:cnTF` which is defined as a variant of `\__prop_split:NnTF`. However, I can't find this in `interface3,pdf`. On the other hand, it is in `l3kernel/expl3-code.tex`, so I guess it should work?

Comment: before `calligraphy` you also need to load library `decorations.pathreplacing`.

Comment: @Zarko I already added `decorations`. Making it `decorations.pathreplacing` doesn't help. You only need that, I think, for calligraphic brackets and such. That code is conditionalised on the decorations stuff being defined.

Comment: @Zarko Oops, but I see I didn't add it here. Thanks. Doesn't change the error. (I don't think it is really needed. But just in case.)

Comment: For `\__prop_split:NnTF` see page 148 of `interface3.pdf` (version dated 2018/03/05)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue here is those `−` symbols: they are *not* 'hyphen-minus' (`-`). You are getting a somewhat cryptic error as LaTeX2e 2018-onwards enables UTF-8 support as-standard for pdfTeX. In an expansion context, a (non-ASCII) UTF-8 char will give some odd results under such a scheme, but it was never 'right'. Replacing the characters by a standard hyphen deals with the issue.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_zero_new:N \g__prg_map_int 
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\tikz \calligraphy [copperplate] (0,0) .. controls +(1,-1) and +(-1,1) .. ++(3,0) [this stroke
style={light,taper=start}] +(0,0) .. controls
+(1,-1) and +(-1,1) .. ++(3,0) [this stroke
style={heavy}] +(0,0) .. controls +(1,-1) and
+(-1,1) .. ++(3,0) [this stroke
style={light,taper=end}] ;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean the `-1` in the coordinates? I guess I shouldn't have copied an example from the manual?

Comment: i took a liberty and ad image produced by your code :-)