# recent l3kernel package and TikZ library calligraphy are not compatible

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3

Today I update my MikTeX installation. Among updated packages is `l3kernel` which doesn't work with `calligraphy` library, even if it is not used in TikZ picture:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy
                }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0) --(3,0) node [right] {$t$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives error:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'nnV' deprecated for base form '\spath_get:nnN'.
(LaTeX3)        One should not change an argument from type 'N' to type 'V':
(LaTeX3)        base form only accepts a single token argument.

Type <return> to continue.
```

After abandoning of compilation editor open file `spath3.sty` and indicate that error has source in line 197:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \spath_get:nnN {nnV,VnN,VnV}
```

Since I frequently use the `calligraphy` I stuck with my temporary LaTeX project. It had problem with `l3...` packages before, but it had been managed with temporary fix provided in [Joseph Wright answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442132/undefined-sequence-error-with-calligraphy-tikz-library):

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_zero_new:N \g__prg_map_int
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

but this temporary fix is not sufficient anymore :-(.

**addendum:**
meanwhile i had private correspondence wit author of the package `spath3` and `tikz` libraries `calligraphy` and `knots` (among others). I had privilege to test new version of the package and libraries. The tests has been successful, so we can expect that new version of `spath3` bundle (package, libraries) will be on the way to CTAN soon.

Thank you to all who with their comments help me, special thanks is going to Andrew Stacey, the authors of the package and libraries, who respond so quickly and provide new version of package and libraries.

Comment: A single “illegal” variant is used in `\SPathInfoInto`. The package `spath3` should be updated in order to fix this; by the way, the definition of `\SPathInfoInto` is flawed anyway. And the `\spath_get:nnV` variant is meaningless.

Comment: Add to your fix `\RenewDocumentCommand{\SPathInfoInto}{mmm}{\spath_get:nnN{#1}{#2}#3}`. In order to remove the warnings, there's nothing else to do than waiting for an update. By the way, I get warnings and not errors.

Comment: @egreg  I get a warning in texlive but an error in miktex - and in miktex expl3 is newer (2019-01-01) then in texlive (2018-12-12 L3). That's rather odd.

Comment: @egreg, unfortunately your fix for `expl3` from 1.1.2019 doesn't help. Now i'm in big troubles due to large numbers of my images use  the `calligraphy`package. who knows how long we will need to way for new version of the `calligraphy` package ... :-( anyway, thenk you very much for help!

Comment: Make a local copy of `spath3.sty`, in which you remove the rogue `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` commands on line 197. Fix also `\SPathInfoInto` as indicated and add the other fix at the beginning. Then mail the package author.

Comment: @egreg, thank you very much for suggestion. i will try this during Sunday, now is time for sleep :-)

Comment: Better yet, add at the start, just before the first `\tl_new:Nn` instruction, `\int_new:N \g__spath_map_int` and replace every occurrence of `\g__prg_map_int` with `\g__spath_map_int`.

Comment: @egreg, i do as you suggested: (i) store original `spath3.sty` (as spath3-original), (ii) remove ˙line 197 with `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \spath_get:nnN {nnV,VnN,VnV},  (iii) store corrected `spath3` . Now works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zarko I mailed the author.

Comment: @egreg, me too, just now  :)

Comment: Hi all.  The plethora of emails I just received led me to this question!  Could you try to regenerate the files from spath3.dtx available from https://github.com/loopspace/spath3 and let me know if that fixes things. If so, I'll get it uploaded to CTAN.

Comment: @LoopSpace, i try to extract `spath3`, however since i'm not familiar with `dtx` files, so there i high probability  that i made same basics errors. the resulted `spath3.sty` doesn't works ... it has a bunch of text belonging to comments. please, can you provide as addition to dtx. file already extracted `spath3.sty` file for test?

Comment: @Zarko I'll email it to you, but FYI running `tex spath3.dtx` generates the new files "behind the scenes".  You see a load of comments in the terminal, but it also writes out the files.

Comment: @LoopSpace Thanks for the github link. As far as I could see this is not in ctan yet so let me confirm that this fixes the problem. Thanks btw for your package!

Comment: @Andrew, i used it regularly. it works fine. it is awesome package.

Comment: Thanks for the prod - I've just uploaded it to CTAN.  Fingers crossed that I managed to do it correctly!