# tikz and calligraphy still don't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, calligraphy

Despite using advice from answers to the two questions [(1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442132/undefined-sequence-error-with-calligraphy-tikz-library) and [(2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408378/warning-with-tikzlibrary-calligraphy), when I try to compile

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calligraphy}

\begin{document}
  test
\end{document}
```

there are still many error messages. Is it possible to fix this in the document?

**Edit:**

I get the following errors:

```
spath3.sty:197: LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'VnV' deprecated for base form '\spath_get:nnN'.
spath3.sty:197: LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'nnV' deprecated for base form '\spath_get:nnN'.
tikzlibrarycalligraphy.code.tex:707: Undefined control sequence.
tikzlibrarycalligraphy.code.tex:707: You can't use `\mathchar"1' after \advance.
tikzlibrarycalligraphy.code.tex:707: You can't use `the letter :' after \the.
```

I use `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)`.

Comment: I haven't any errors on your code. What is, please, your LaTeX distribution? What's the mistake you get? Thank you.

Comment: good point, I added more info.

Comment: problem is in `spath` package which is used in caligraphy. Author of this package sent me (jan, 6) a new version of package which eliminate all problems. this new version should be now on ctan (i didn't check this). see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442132/undefined-sequence-error-with-calligraphy-tikz-library, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408378/warning-with-tikzlibrary-calligraphy, 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468763/recent-l3kernel-package-and-tikz-library-calligraphy-are-not-compatible

Comment: Unfortunately, the version on ctan is from 2016…

Comment: Did you try to download and install `spath3` from [this repository](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3)? This did the trick for me when writing [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471222/121799). I just checked, when not using the downloaded version but what comes with TeXLive I reproduce your error, but it disappears with the style file from the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem when writing [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471222/121799). And on my original TeXLive distribution I do reproduce your error messages. To fix it,

1. Download the more recent version from [this repository](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3).
2. Run `tex spath3.dtx` on the terminal.
3. Copy the thus produced style file `spath3.sty` in the same directory where the TeX file you want to compile is.

This did the trick for me. (I'll be happy to remove this if it does not solve your problem or LoopSpace tells me to do so.)